# Drag and Drop problem, Files won't drop in OS X

Tags: macos, finder

I have a MacBook Pro 15" i7, Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Files won't "drop" after dragging them.

I've restarted my computer several times, and repaired disk permissions as well as verified the disk – and the results told me my MacBook Pro was fine.

What should I do? What's causing this?

Comment: What happens instead? Does it snap back? Sometimes it may stick and you have to click to drop. Does that work?

Comment: Where are you actually trying to drag/drop files from/to?

Comment: Double click to drop if you have Drag Lock on.

Comment: thanks guys. what happened was, my computer worked fine before, i don't have drag lock on, so it should automatically drop to another folder like if i dragged from my desktop to photos. it didn't drop. it was stuck moving around with the cursor. when i press esc, it wouldn't snap back to the desktop.

Comment: So you use the trackpad only? How do you perform the drag then? Do you have "dragging" enabled (i.e. double-click, then drag) or do you click the pad and drag? Or is your problem solved?

Comment: Yup, i use the trackpad. Double-click, then drag. It might be because I sprayed (lightly) some cleaning agent on my keyboard? could that be the problem? I woke up today and found it was working; the fluid must have dried up?

Comment: Maybe — if it works you can answer your own question and say, "I did this, it must have been that, etc.". You could also accept this answer in two days.

Comment: it's still not working again..

Answer (score 3):

An anonymous user posted the following as a suggested edit to one of the answers to this question:

> This seems to be related to Avatron's Air Display, see [this post](http://blog.avatron.com/post/20422624624/air-display-on-lion-with-nvidia-9400-9600).

From the linked web  page:

> Here’s the current status: **IF you’re running Lion AND if you have an NVIDIA 9400M/9600M chipset AND you have a third-party video driver installed, THEN you will not be able to release the mouse button while drag-dropping something.**
>
> Well, it turns out that the drag-drop bug only manifests itself if you haven’t done a Wake From Sleep since your last Log In or Restart. So there’s a workaround: **After each Log In or Restart, close your MacBook Pro, wait for it to sleep, and then open it again to wake it.** It’s a little bit of a pain, but it’s there as a workaround if you want to use Air Display on one of these Macs.

Answer (score 2):

That happens to me in Lion after I boot my computer.

My solution: **put it to sleep and wake it and everything will be ok**

Comment: Against all my expectations, this actually works *reliably* to solve the issue. And all this time, I've been rebooting my entire machine (I never use ‘sleep.’) So: As of El Capitan, this is still a fix for this strange, elusive, and ever-present OS X bug … at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open *System Preferences » Trackpad* and make sure you don't have *Drag Lock* set there.

Comment: Is there even a difference between Drag Lock activated and the default setting? Couldn't spot any.

Comment: @slhck Just watch the video. You can remove your fingers while dragging. It's gone on Lion, so I cannot experiment myself /// Totally off topic: May I send you an SU blog post draft by email for feedback?

Comment: Ah, so there's no automatic deactivation anymore. /// Why yes, I'll read through it some time tomorrow or over the weekend!

Comment: @Daniel Beck the drag lock setting is actually still there in lion, albeit in the Universal Access section buried underneath 2 layers of settings.

Comment: I don't have drag lock selected. It's probably something with my trackpad? thanks for the help though.